Laptop discharges even when the battery percentage is more than 20%
Although I am currently using Pop!_OS 22.04, I faced the same issue when I was using Ubuntu.
So, my dual-booted laptop (Lenovo Yoga S740) occasionally shuts down in the middle of my work even when the battery percentage is not zero. It happens around 30-35 %, which is why I don't connect the charger. When I plug the charger in and turn the laptop back on, the battery percentage is zero.
This doesn't happen regularly, but it is frequent enough to be not taken as a one-off incident. Sometimes, my laptop keeps working even though the battery percentage is like 5 %. So I don't know how to replicate it.
What could be the possible reason? And how do I prevent this from happening? Is there like a "true" battery power indicator or are there any settings or commands to fix my battery indicator.

Is the laptop a few years old? I had a laptop with a similar problem. It turned out to be a battery issue. After a few months, the laptop kept turning off even when the battery percent was 60%, then 80%, and eventually it turned off as soon as I removed the charger. The solution was to buy a new battery

My laptop is 4 years old. Did you also face the problem occasionally at the start? Cause this thing only happens sometimes.
Another incident where this is a bit more common is when it's around 30% on ubuntu and then I switch to Windows. Which turns on and then powers off due to low battery.

I started facing this problem after the laptop was 3.5 years old. It seems that the battery is sending wrong information about its percentage. It is sending 30% when it is actually 0.

So is there any way by which one can show the actual battery percentage? Or it's purely a hardware problem (battery)?

I believe it is a hardware problem. In a few months the battery might completely die

I’m voting to close this question because it is a hardware issue
